# When and why do I need background.html or background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first Chrome extension. I've gone through Chrome developer documentation, but I couldn't comprehend few topics.

What I've understood:

1. There are two actions:

   - **Browser action** (button outside address bar)
   - **page action** (button inside address bar)
2. For both actions we have **background pages**:

   - Background pages can be `background.html` or `background.js` for browser actions
   - Or `background.html` or `eventPage.js` for page actions

I am using a page action. For default popup page I used `popup.html`.

Now where does this `background.html` and `eventPage.js` fit in (especially `background.html`, as I already have my `popup.html`, do I need that?)

What should `eventPage.js` have? What should `background.html` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `manifest.json`, if you're using an ["event page"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (recommended to reduce your extension's memory use) you'll have something like

```
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "page": "eventPage.html"
    "persistent": false
  },
  ...
}
```

Now, the above manifest won't actually work: you can only have *one* of the `"scripts"` or `"page"` key in the `"background"` dictionary. The simplest thing to do is define `"scripts"`. Then you can write a bunch of javascript, and have it run in response to various events like [chrome.runtime.onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) and [chrome.pageAction.onClicked](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#event-onClicked).

The javascript you list in the `"scripts"` key runs in the context of an HTML document and can use DOM APIs like [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) while it's running. By default, Chrome will generate a document of the form:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="event.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

to hold the scripts you list. You'll see this in chrome://extensions/ if you click on the "background page" link next to "Inspect views". However, sometimes you might want that document to have more elements pre-defined. I've seen examples like:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="event.js"></script>
    <canvas width="300" height="400" id="the_canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

so `event.js` can use `document.getElementById('the_canvas')` to retrieve a canvas it can draw on. Without the custom document, your javascript could still run:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 400;
```

and get the same result, but the document can be easier. That HTML file is what you'd put in the `background.page` key in your manifest.

As @SirDemon mentioned, you can sometimes get away with no background/event page at all, if you put everything into a [browser action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)'s popup. Because a [page action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) is supposed to only appear for pages it's relevant to, you'll usually need a background/event page to control the page action.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily *need* a background page or background script. If you intend to create an extension that does not require any human interaction, then you *would* need them.

Page and browser actions usually mean you intend to have some sort of UI, so no need for background stuff. Just add your scripts etc to your main 'default_popup' html page as you would normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SirDemon. I just found that as I'm using a pageaction, to display my page ,I need to call a method and that method requires tabID. To get TabID i have to contentScript.js and send a call to eventPage.js according to https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-extensions/47hx1yoM04c/discussion . I've done so, but it is not working.Can u help me out please.

Comment: First, in order to work with tabs, it is best to add 'tabs' to your permissions manifest. Beyond that, I would need to know exactly what is failing in your code to know how to help.